# Raven DB HTTP API - Property Traversal

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I am given the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "document": {
        "sections": {
            "x": {
                "title": "foo"
            },
            "y": {
                "title": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I update value of the title property for a given section using the HTTP API?

I would like to provide a path (string) to get to the property.

Comment: You should be able to use a scripted patch command, but I ran into a bug while producing an example for you.  It works with the bulk_docs interface, but not for a single doc.  See my comments [in the bug report](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-810)

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson for logging the bug.  
  
ScriptedPatchRequest --  

This is an ultimate feature in Raven DB that I missed out completely (probably due to the faint documentation out there and the name).  Having IronJS support is AWESOME! It definitely deserves more attention and a cleaner impl as Matt pointed out.  
Ayende’s blog post on this topic is helpful - http://ayende.com/blog/157185/awesome-ravendb-feature-of-the-day-evil-patching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in build 2254.  You should now be able to issue a single scripted patch like this:

```
EVAL http://localhost:8080/docs/foos/1

{Script:"this.document.sections.x.title = newTitle;",Values:{"newTitle":"Whatever"}}
```